# Error: At line 463 of file custom.f90: Memory allocation failed

Tags: python, memory, allocation, gekko

I am facing an issue when scaling up my optimisation model. Here is a minimal example, which results in the stated error, when given enough entities to process. You can adjust the number of entities to be processed at the top of the code snippet.

Ideally, this script should run for tens of thousands of entities.

I appreciate the help! Thank you a lot :-)

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from tqdm import tqdm
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import math
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm, poisson
from gekko import GEKKO


NUM_ENTITIES = 50 # 10 crashes already... just a few work out fine

np.random.seed(321)
di_kde = dict()

for entity in range(NUM_ENTITIES):
    arr = np.random.normal(14.75, 6, 500)
    kernel = gaussian_kde(arr, bw_method='scott')
    di_kde[entity] = (kernel, int(np.amax(arr)), int(np.amin(arr)))


def normcdf_gekko(yi, mean, sd):
    y = 0.5*(1 + m.erf((yi-mean)/(sd*m.sqrt(2.0))))
    z = m.if3(1-y, 1, y)
    return z

def cdf_gauss_nogecko(kdes, maxi):

    bw = kdes.neff**(-1./(1+4))
    res = np.divide(np.cumsum([sum([norm.pdf(i, val, bw) for val in kdes.dataset.flatten()]) for i in np.linspace(0, maxi, 100, endpoint=True)]), max(np.cumsum([sum([norm.pdf(i, val, bw) for val in kdes.dataset.flatten()]) for i in np.linspace(0, maxi, 100, endpoint=True)])))
    return res

def cdf_gauss_singular_gecko(kdes, yi):

    bw = kdes.neff**(-1./(1+4))
    res = m.sum([normcdf_gekko(yi, val, bw) for val in kdes.dataset.flatten()]) / kdes.dataset.flatten().size
    return res

def cdf_gauss_singular_nogecko(kdes, yi):

    bw = kdes.neff**(-1./(1+4))
    res = np.sum([norm.cdf(yi, val, bw) for val in kdes.dataset.flatten()]) / kdes.dataset.flatten().size
    return res

def pdf_gauss_gekko(kdes, yi):

    bw = kdes.neff**(-1./(1+4))
    res_gecko = m.sum([normpdf_gekko(yi, val, bw) for val in kdes.dataset.flatten()])
    
    return res_gecko

def normpdf_gekko(x, mean, sd):
    var = float(sd)**2
    denom = m.sqrt((2*math.pi*var))
    num = m.exp(-(x-float(mean))**2/(2*var))
    return num/denom

cost = 0.1
revenue = 1

print(f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S ")}Running optimisation under constraint...')

if not os.path.isdir(os.path.abspath(r'.\Logging')):
    os.mkdir(os.path.abspath(r'.\Logging'))

m = GEKKO(remote=True) # Initialize gekko
#m.time = np.linspace(0,20,100)

m._path = os.path.abspath(r'.\Logging')

m.options.SOLVER = 3  # APOPT (1) is an MINLP solver
m.options.IMODE = 3 # 3 or 6
m.options.MAX_MEMORY = 10

m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 500', \
                    # minlp iterations with integer solution
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10', \
                    # treat minlp as nlp
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                    # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first
                    'minlp_branch_method 2', \
                    # maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']


print(f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S ")}Adding variables...')

qi = [m.FV(value=di_kde[k][1] , lb=di_kde[k][2], ub=di_kde[k][1], integer=True, name=f'qi_{k}') for idx, k in enumerate(di_kde.keys())]


print(f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S ")}Adding constraint equations...')

inter = m.Intermediate(m.sum([cdf_gauss_singular_gecko(di_kde[k][0], qi[idx4]) for idx4, k in enumerate(di_kde.keys())]) / len(di_kde), name='InterConstr')
m.Equation(inter >= 0.9)


print(f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S ")}Adding maximisation function...')

for ii, kk in enumerate(di_kde.keys()):
    m.Maximize(m.sum([(-cost * (m.max3(0, qi[ii]-j) + m.max3(0, j-qi[ii]) + qi[ii]) + revenue * m.min3(qi[ii], j)) * pdf_gauss_gekko(di_kde[kk][0], j) for j in range(di_kde[kk][2], di_kde[kk][1])]))
    

print(f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S ")}Start solving...')

m.open_folder()
m.options.DIAGLEVEL=10
output = m.solve(disp=True)


print(f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S ")}End solving...')
print('Results')
print('qi: ' + str(qi))
print('constraint: ' + str(inter.value))
print('Objective: ' + str(-m.options.objfcnval))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! But we are not the maintainers of `gekko`, so this may not be the proper forum for a bug report. In any case, your question should include the full stack trace of the error, not just the message. You should not expect us to work out for ourselves where line 463 is.

Comment: The stack trace is not accessible to the audience and myself, since the error results from an executable and is passed forward to Python and truncated strongly. 

I actually was encouraged by the maintainer to post here instead of on GitHub to have a greater audience :-) https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues/133

Answer (score 2):

The size of the model scales with `NUM_ENTITIES` as `55486*NUM_ENTITIES-2008` with `53,224`, `109,470`, `164,195` lines for `NUM_ENTITIES=1,2,3` in `gk0_model.apm` in the `m.path` run directory.

**Model Lines versus NUM_ENTITIES**

[image: Model Lines]

Inspecting the model files shows a lot of simple equations that could be reduced. For example, about 30% of the model lines are these equations:

```
    v54786=((exp(-951.5365149722506))/(sqrt(0.5231086080192687)))
    v54787=((exp(-1699.0345902817821))/(sqrt(0.5231086080192687)))
    v54788=((exp(-1123.400950839389))/(sqrt(0.5231086080192687)))
    v54789=((exp(-2752.8539627322))/(sqrt(0.5231086080192687)))
    v54790=((exp(-4449.244551756981))/(sqrt(0.5231086080192687)))
```

These could be replaced by a simple evaluation in Python to remove the variables and the equations. You may also see other opportunities as you inspect `gk0_model.apm`.

There is `m.options.REDUCE=1` that automatically removes the simple assignment equations or `m.options.REDUCE=2` or higher to successively scan and remove simple equations. However, you may want to do it in Python to avoid a large `.apm` file write and speed up the model compile time.