# How can I simplify a large scale NLP model in Gekko Python?

Tags: python, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I'm still new to Gekko optimization in Python, and I have a problem scaling up my NLP problem.
After trying to call several times (And in different ways) the function m.Sum, using m.Intermediate and using list comprehensions for reducing the size of the string representing my model, I still get this error while trying to optimize a model that only has 200 variables. The model works when I optimize for only 80 variables.

This is the error I get:

```
APM model error: string > 15000  characters
 Consider breaking up the line into multiple equations

 The may also be due to only using newline character CR
   instead of CR LF (for Windows) or LF (for MacOS/Linux)
 To fix this problem, save APM file with appropriate newline characters

 STOPPING...
```

Here's a snippet of the code that's getting me in trouble:

```
def function_to_minimize(variables0,m):
    somme = [ m.Intermediate(
                    variables0[0+(4*i)] * df['value1'][i] + \
                    variables0[1+(4*i)] * df['value2'][i] + \
                    variables0[2+(4*i)] * df['value3'][i] + \
                    variables0[3+(4*i)] * df['value4'][i]
     ) for i in range(0,hours)] 

    somme = reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, somme)
    m.Obj(m.Intermediate(somme))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `m.Obj()` multiple times instead of creating a summation. Below is a minimal complete problem that demonstrates the issue. If `v = m.Array(m.Var,100,lb=0,ub=10)` is an array of more variables then the 15,000 equation length limit could be reached.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
v = m.Array(m.Var,100,lb=0,ub=10)
hours = 24
def function_to_minimize(variables0,m):
    somme = [ m.Intermediate(
                    variables0[0+(4*i)] * 1 + \
                    variables0[1+(4*i)] * 2 + \
                    variables0[2+(4*i)] * 3 + \
                    variables0[3+(4*i)] * 4
     ) for i in range(0,hours)] 
    somme = sum(somme)
    m.Minimize(m.Intermediate(somme))
function_to_minimize(v,m)
m.solve()
```

Use `m.sum()` to avoid the limit.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()
v = m.Array(m.Var,100,lb=0,ub=10)
hours = 24

def function_to_minimize(variables0,m):
    somme = [ m.Intermediate(
                    variables0[0+(4*i)] * 1 + \
                    variables0[1+(4*i)] * 2 + \
                    variables0[2+(4*i)] * 3 + \
                    variables0[3+(4*i)] * 4
     ) for i in range(0,hours)] 

    m.Minimize(m.sum(somme))
function_to_minimize(v,m)
m.solve()
```

or call `m.Obj()` or `m.Minimize()` separately for each element with `[m.Minimize(s) for s in somme]`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()
v = m.Array(m.Var,100,lb=0,ub=10)
hours = 24

def function_to_minimize(variables0,m):
    somme = [ m.Intermediate(
                    variables0[0+(4*i)] * 1 + \
                    variables0[1+(4*i)] * 2 + \
                    variables0[2+(4*i)] * 3 + \
                    variables0[3+(4*i)] * 4
     ) for i in range(0,hours)] 

    [m.Minimize(s) for s in somme]
function_to_minimize(v,m)
m.solve()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I've tried the three versions of your code, but the limit is reached. I want to use more than 10k variables, is there a way to override this limit?

Comment: The third option should never reach the equation length limit. Could you open the gk0_model.apm file in the run directory to determine what equation is too long? Try m.open_folder()

Comment: I checked the model file as told and realized that anouther equation was getting me in trouble. Thank you for your help, my code seems to work pretty well now. Thank you.

Comment: It's me again Professor @JohnHedengren, the scale up using this tip worked for passing from 80 variables to 800, but now I'm trying to scale up to 2000 variables and I get this message: 
`
Memory allocation failed

Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for additional error details
`
I tried using other IMODE and solvers, but my problem is MINLP so technically I can only use APOPT.... Do you know what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Try reducing the number of fixed parameters or constants that you declare in the model. You can replace those with numbers. There are other ways to avoid creating additional gekko variables. If this doesn't help, then please post a new question with a minimal working example.

Comment: Here are some additional suggestions that may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256978/error-at-line-463-of-file-custom-f90-memory-allocation-failed/70308790#70308790