# Gekko Python: Memory allocation failed

Tags: python, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gekko, mixed-integer-programming

As a follow up to the question:
[How can I simplify a large scale NLP model in Gekko Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72907917/how-can-i-simplify-a-large-scale-nlp-model-in-gekko-python)
I'm still trying to figure out why gekko gets me this error:

> Memory allocation failed
>
> Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for additional error
> details

These are my constraints:

```
def contraintesPuissance(self):

    Pmin = self.df_donnees_techniques["Puissance min"].to_list()
    Pmax = self.df_donnees_techniques["Puissance max"].to_list()

    self.model.Equations(
    [
        [
            self.on_off_var[ idx + (heure*self.nb_actifs) ] \
                * Pmax[idx] / self.getRendement(idx,heure) \
                - self.variables[ idx + (heure*self.nb_actifs) ] >= 0,

            self.variables[ idx + (heure*self.nb_actifs) ] \
                - self.on_off_var[ idx + (heure*self.nb_actifs) ] \
                * Pmin[idx] / self.getRendement(idx,heure) >= 0
        ]
        for heure in range(self.nb_heure)
        for idx in range(self.nb_actifs)
    ]
    )

def contraintesBesoinsConsommation(self):
    self.model.Equations(
            [
                [
                    sum([self.variables[idx + (heure*self.nb_actifs)]*self.getRendement(idx,heure) for idx in range(self.nb_actifs)])  \
                        - self.Analyse_df['besoins_chaud'][heure] == 0
                ]
                for heure in range(self.nb_heure)
            ]
        )

def contraintesTxENR(self):
    intermed = [self.model.Intermediate(
                    self.variables[ idx + (heure*self.nb_actifs) ] * self.getRendement(idx,heure)
                ) for heure in range(self.nb_heure) for idx in range(self.nb_actifs)
                ]

    numerateur = self.model.sum(
        [intermed[idx + (heure*self.nb_actifs)] * self.getTaux(idx) for heure in range(self.nb_heure) for idx in range(self.nb_actifs)]
    )
    denominateur = self.model.sum(intermed)

    self.model.Equation( numerateur / denominateur - self.Tx_ENR_cible >= 0)

def contrainteEmissions(self):
    self.model.Equation( self.VLE_max_gaz - self.emissions("Gaz_1") >= 0 )
    # !! à arrêter
```

And this is my objective function:

```
    def func_cout_NRJV2_gekko(self):

    somme = [
        sum([self.variables[ idx + (heure*self.nb_actifs) ] * self.donnees_prix_NRJ[self.actifs_instancies[idx]][heure] for idx in range(self.nb_actifs)])
    for heure in range(self.nb_heure)]      
    [self.model.Minimize(s) for s in somme]
    penalite = self.model.if3(self.Sum_NRJ("Bois") - self.take_or_pay_bois, self.penalite_bois, 0) # Penalité take or pay
    self.model.Minimize(penalite)
```

If more info is needed, I can provide it, but the code is really big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS are you using? The issue with `Memory allocation failed` may be that the problem is >4 GB. On Local solve: Linux / MacOS and Cloud solve: Linux it isn't a problem because the executables are 64-bit. For Windows, the local executable is still 32-bit so the RAM limitation may be reached. This will likely change in the near future, but it could be the limitation.

Here are a few things to try, even if you are on a 64-bit executable.

1. Inspect the model by opening the local run folder with `m.open_folder()`. Open the `gk0_model.apm` file with a text editor. The variables will have different internal names. They can be changed by naming variables with the `name` argument such as `x = m.Var(value=0,name='x')` to make it more readable.
2. Convert any Constants or Parameters to just regular Python numbers. This can greatly reduce the memory requirement because they are not added to the automatic differentiation.
3. If there are summations that can be `np.sum()` instead of `m.sum()`, use that instead so parts of the model are pre-computed before giving it to the solver.
4. Use `m.options.REDUCE=3` to scan through the model 3 (or more) times to reduce the memory requirements. This eliminates equations such as `x==1`, `y+x==1`, and ``` z+y+x==`` by replacing them with ``` x=1`,` y=0`,` z=0` as a pre-solve.
5. The `if3()` function creates a few extra variables and equations and can increase the size of the model. If some of the conditions are always greater than zero or less than zero with pre-processing, then try eliminating those.

Comment: Thanks again for such a clear explanation. I already did every thing that you mention in my model but I'm actually wondering if the problem is rather on the solution space, because I'm using at least 2*k binary variables and therefore the algorithm has to search in a huge space with a combinatorial explosion... Leaving me with a problem that needs more than 4Gb which I find really big for k=744...

Comment: That is a big problem! Maybe try solving with `m.options.SOLVER=3` initially to see if it can solve the NLP first.